# Sticky nav and scroll to top confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sticky nav in the middle of the page (Agenda days) that becomes fixed while the content of the sticky nav is being scrolled down.  The nav is Bootstrap tabs, this is how the HTML look like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs followMeBar agenda-days text-center">
  <li class="active"><a class="day" href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Day 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="day" href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Day 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="day" href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Day 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the tab contents are located in divs with corresponding ids, like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="1">
    <h3>Day 1</h3>
```

Everything is working fine except one thing, if you are half way scrolled down on Day 1 and then click on Day 2, the content switches to Day 2 but you're still halfway scrolled down. How do I make Day 1, Day 2, Day 3 to switch the content AND scroll to the top of the Agenda content (not to the top of the page).

Here's my full code example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POvGPr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add class to li container of days link. Second for instance add a selector before days navigation.

```
<div class="test"></div>

<li class="active scroll-top"><a  href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Day 1</a></li>

  $('.scroll-top').click(function(){
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".test").offset().top},
       'slow');
  });
```

Comment: Awsome! and it makes sense. I updated the pen, works like a charm. Thank you Stefano :)